# display 2 columns side by side, Bootstrap XS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display 2 columns side by side (not stacked) in bootstrap. I want it to be arranged this way on the mobile screen size "XS" too. The example works the way I want on SM but not XS screen sizes. Also attached a sketch of what I want to achieve in the end. As well as the HTML that I have so far. I’m using default bootstrap CSS and JS.

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQPju.jpg)

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="row" >
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <ul data-menuTitle="Main Menu" >
              <li><a accesskey="a" href="#">Ride Bike</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="b" href="#">Get Fit</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="c" href="#">Visit Store</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="d" href="#">Ride Bike</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="e" href="#">Get Fit</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="f" href="#">Visit Store</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <ul data-menuTitle="Main Menu" >
              <li><a accesskey="g" href="#">Ride Bike</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="h" href="#">Get Fit</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="i" href="#">Visit Store</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="j" href="#">Ride Bike</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="k" href="#">Get Fit</a></li>
              <li><a accesskey="l" href="#">Visit Store</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- end of nested row nav-->
    </div>
  </nav><!-- end of row nav-->
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: Instead of this col-sx-6 use this col-xs-6 every where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `col-sx-*`, it's `col-xs-*`. And `col-sm-12` is the same as `col-xs-12` with how you have it setup, you won't need both.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>Main Navigation</h2>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <ul data-menuTitle="Main Menu">
            <li><a accesskey="a" href="#">Ride Bike</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="b" href="#">Get Fit</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="c" href="#">Visit Store</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="d" href="#">Ride Bike</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="e" href="#">Get Fit</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="f" href="#">Visit Store</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <ul data-menuTitle="Main Menu">
            <li><a accesskey="g" href="#">Ride Bike</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="h" href="#">Get Fit</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="i" href="#">Visit Store</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="j" href="#">Ride Bike</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="k" href="#">Get Fit</a>

            </li>
            <li><a accesskey="l" href="#">Visit Store</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of nested row nav-->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of row nav-->
</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: vanburenx that was du' moment on my part.

Comment: It happens to us all, glad I could help!